# Можно ли "как всегда" открыть запятой, а закрыть тире?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

> Старикашечка, как всегда – насмешничал, потом рассказал несколько
>   удивительных автобиографических эпизодов и только потом мы приступили
>   к делу <римское барокко>. Таковы знаки его высочайшего расположения.

Запятую перед *и только* не поставила, ибо в сомнениях. Дело, к которому приступили, тоже входит в ритуал отношений наставник - внимающий. Я права?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что здесь возможны **такие варианты:**

(1) **Как всегда,** старикашечка насмешничал, потом рассказал несколько удивительных автобиографических эпизодов и только потом мы приступили к делу <римское барокко>.

Общее вводное слово, запятой нет.

(2) Старикашечка насмешничал **– как всегда,** потом рассказал несколько удивительных автобиографических эпизодов, и только потом мы приступили к делу <римское барокко>.

Обособление вводного слова с помощью тире. Запятая ставится, так как нет общего элемента.

Answer (score 1):

***Старикашечка, как всегда, насмешничал, потом рассказал несколько удивительных автобиографических эпизодов,  и только потом мы приступили к делу <римское барокко>. Таковы знаки его высочайшего расположения.***

Запятую перед И надо поставить: предложение сложное, события следуют одно за другим, общего второстепенного члена  нет.

Последнее предложение оформлено правильно.

Comment: Катюшечка, тут такое... эээ... акцентированное тире после *как всегда*, как с ним быть, чтобы сохранить?

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие можно, а тире нельзя.

Двоеточие ставится перед "подробностями", тире приравнивает текст по обе стороны (кроме случаев пропуска слов и интонаций).

Стремление сохранить тире — грубейшая ошибка: авторская пунктуация тоже должна быть в рамках здравого смысла. Иначе нет смысла искать поддержки на форуме "Русский язык".

И тут ни в коем случае не "обойдёшься" запятой и тире, и тем более тире не съест запятую. Это противоречит всем нормам пунктуации, тут даже говорить не о чем.

Comment: А из зала мне кричат: "Давай подробности!"

Comment: Двоеточие ставится перед "подробностями", тире приравнивает текст по обе стороны (кроме случаев пропуска слов и интонаций).

Comment: Было бы замечательно, если бы вы как-нибудь обосновали свой ответ (в ответе, а не в комментариях) :)